# URL Rewriting in. Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, rewriting

I have a website on a test server and I want to rewrite URL for this website because it is very long

I wish our visitors instead of entering this URL:

http://staging.company.fr/site2.it/s...oject2/public/

enter this URL:

www.monsite.com

I created a file. htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/~(.+) http://www.monsite.com/~$1 [NC,L]
```

but does not work

Answer (score 0):

While in `.htaccess` mod_rewrite doesn't match leading slash in a URL since it is applied per directory. Therefore following should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.monsite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

This will redirect every URL in your existing domain other than home `/` to `monsite.com`

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'll check